# Exposing private properties with categories

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, objective-c-category

I want to expose a view controller's private properties so that I can test them. One way to do that is by creating a category on the class just for testing and use a category method to get the value out.

```
// Class I want to test -- implementation
#import "SomeViewController.h"

@interface SomeViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic)UIActionSheet *sheet;
@end

// Category's header
#import "SomeViewController.h"

@interface SomeViewController (Test)
-(UIActionSheet *)getSheetValue;
@end

// Category's implementation
#import "SomeViewController+Test.h"

@implementation SomeViewController (Test)
-(UIActionSheet *)getSheetValue{
    return self.sheet;    // references private property
}
@end
```

Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking maybe I could just create a public `sheet` property on the category that referenced the private property's value but can't find any good documentation on how to go about it. What's the best practice for testing private properties without relying on ivars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privately the methods you need already exist, the category just needs to make them visible to the test:

```
@interface SomeViewController (Test)

- (UIActionSheet *) sheet;

@end
```

you don't need to implement that method, but now you can use it. You will only have issues if you make a method visible but which doesn't actually exist at runtime.

Comment: Interesting. Xcode generates a warning, `Method definition for 'sheet' not found`

Comment: Where is that warning at (which line)? Usually you could write the category at the top of the test file instead of in a completely different file.

Comment: In the category's implementation, on `@implementation SomeViewController (Test)`

Comment: You shouldn't have a category implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `valueForKey:`, but it's not as "clean" since you don't get auto-complete and could break if you rename the property via the refactor tool. But it's another option if you don't want to create the category.